# Unexpected message "No users are currently logged in."

Tags: pi-4

I have a Pi that runs a dedicated application - full screen on a 7" touchscreen.

A user reported that they went to use the app and found a white screen with the following message:

**"No users are currently connected. Users will be identified as soon as they connect."**

I have never seen this message and have no idea what app might have displayed it. Sort of sounds like it might be a group chat app of some kind.

Does it ring any bells for anyone?

DG

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: It is probably a message from the application. I have not seen this message anywhere in Linux or standard software for the Pi.

Comment: @jsotola My question is can anyone tell me of an app that generates this message. My app definitely doesn't.

Comment: @DavidG could check system logs for that timeframe and see if you see any logging that matches up.

Answer (score 0):

This message comes from RealVNC Server, which is a remote control program that is pre-installed on Pi.

I have no idea how RealVNC came to be invoked. Almost makes me think it might have been a hacking attempt?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).